# Can I create host-specific users in Postgres? (ex: postgres@localhost)

Tags: security, postgresql

## My Question

Can I set permissions on a user (ex: `postgres`) such that that user is only allowed to login from TCP localhost, but not the Internet?

## Trusted Sockets vs Passwords for Remotes

I get that you can initialize postgres to allow local users to login without a password, and remote hosts to login with a password:

```sh
initdb \
            -D "$POSTGRES_DATA_DIR/" \
            --username postgres --pwfile "$PWFILE" \
            --auth-local=trust --auth-host=password
```

## Intranet vs Internet

For any system that's connecting across the internet I want to use a user that has a very, very strong (non-memorable) random 128-bit string.

For local and intranet access, however, I'd prefer to be able to have a username and password that I can remember (and type).

Can I do this... or do I just have to set up one user per system that's allowed to connect, with a `.pgpass` on each? 
(I don't want to share keys in plaintext files between computers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provide any info about your PostgreSQL version, I assume you're using PostgreSQL 12.

> Can I set permissions on a user (ex: postgres) such that that user is only allowed to login from TCP localhost, but not the Internet?

Yes, use [`pg_hba.conf`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/auth-pg-hba-conf.html). You may want to load this first via [`hba_file`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/runtime-config-file-locations.html#GUC-HBA-FILE) runtime configuration.

> For local and intranet access, however, I'd prefer to be able to have a username and password that I can remember (and type).

If you want to add a local-only user protected with a password, add

```
local <database_name> <local-only_user_name> scram-sha-256
```

in your `pg_hba.conf`.

You probably want to create the user first via `CREATE ROLE`:

```sql
CREATE ROLE username LOGIN ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'insert-your-password-here';
```

You may also want to check `host` and `hostssl` record entry to add to your `pg_hba.conf` to configure your intranet and internet based authentication.

Check linked documentations for more info.

Comment: "local: This record matches connection attempts using Unix-domain sockets."
(local is not localhost, which is part of what was tripping me up earlier)

Comment: The comments in my pg_hba.conf did not seem to suggest a username could be specified, but I see the official docs do. Thanks. I'll try this out later today and mark it as the solution if it works. :)